# How to fix authentication error when querying Yelp GraphQL API using Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, yelp

I'm trying to create a basic react app that uses Apollo Client to query the Yelp GraphQL API.

When I try to send a query, I'm receiving a 401 error response.

I've joined the developer Beta program with Yelp and tried refreshing my API key but that hasn't worked. Here's the code for my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo'
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { setContext } from "apollo-link-context";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/graphql",
  fetchOptions: {
    mode: "no-cors"
  }
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = process.env.yelpApiKey;
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
      "Content-Type": "application/graphql"
    }
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App/>
    </ApolloProvider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Am I missing something here? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hey man! can you try to provide an error, or why it doesn't work? any debugging messages. Have you tried debugging, what have you tried?

Comment: The only error message I have in the console is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of api.yelp.com/v3/graphql:1 401 ()". I'm not quite sure what steps I can take to debug. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Error 401 means unauthorized, so probably an issue with the API-key. Try to debug and see if the API-key is correct. check the request and make sure all the headers are correct

Comment: Hey,
I had the same problem, as far as my current understanding goes, the problem lies with Yelp and their Graphql-Server. As soon as you activate "no-cors" your sending the request in a way that their server rejects. See https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1817.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and so far I think that the problem here is Yelp doesn't support CORS, and even we use no-cors It doesn't help.
You can check below discussions.

[GraphQL api returns 500 for a valid query #248](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/248)

[WKWebView CORS error #44](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/44)

I am new at YELP API and I am not super experienced in Apollo Client. But my working solution is as below. I will not use this project for production just development purposes. I used herokuapp to activate cors.

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
// Seting up Apollo Client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/graphql',
  request: (operation) => {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
      },
    });
  },
  cache,
});
```

[image: Status Code: 200 OK]

In this solution I had to use `'Accept-Language': 'en-US',` because without this I got an error 400 Bad request, even en-us is the default;

```
code: "INVALID_LOCALE"
description: "The locale you specified is not valid."
```

Maybe you noticed that I haven't specified

> "Content-Type":"application/graphql"

That is because It costs another 400 Bad requests to us. Apollo Client defaults has a content type "application/json" and when we specified "application/graphql" this overrides. 
You can read a helpful discussion about that in below.

[Getting 400 error "Must Provide Query String" from Yelp GraphQL API (using Apollo Client) #278](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/issues/278)

Also, you can check below screenshot,

[image: Status Code: 400 Bad Request]

I hope this can be helpful for someone, and I know there might be a better solution and If I improve this one I will let you know.